# How to schedule Oozie coordinator every day at the same time?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'd like to set up a simple Oozie coordinator that runs every day at noon, indefinitely.  Is this the proper way to set it up?

```
<coordinator-app name="${jobName}" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="2000-01-01T12:00Z" end="3000-01-01T12:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
    <controls>
        <timeout>-1</timeout>
        <concurrency>1</concurrency>
        <execution>LAST_ONLY</execution>
    </controls>

    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${myAppPath}</app-path>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Thanks,
Alvaro

Comment: Looks good to me. You can dryrun it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write coordinator xml in following way :

```
<coordinator-app name="${jobName}" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="2000-01-01T12:00Z" end="3000-01-01T12:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
<controls>
    <timeout>-1</timeout>
    <concurrency>30</concurrency>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
</controls>
<datasets>
    <dataset name="myData" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="2000-01-01T12:00Z" timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>/time-independent/path/that/may/or/maynot/be/there</uri-template>
    </dataset>
</datasets>
<input-events>
    <data-in name="myInput" dataset="myData">
        <instance>2000-01-01T12:00Z</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
<action>
    <workflow>
        <app-path>${myAppPath}</app-path>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>myInput</name>
                <value>${coord:dataIn('myInput')}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </workflow>
</action>
```

Comment: I think this was the answer to my other question.  I figured out the answer, thanks.